# same performance script can work in different environment

Tags: performance-testing, loadrunner

I have created a scripts for performance testing in PT environment, now the ask is to run same scripts in UAT environment so I have replaced the PT URL to UAT environment URL in my script will that work? if boat environment having same UI and same layers on the application

Comment: Yes. That works! Application should have same UI, configuration and version in both environments.

Comment: That depends, are you using a UI protocol for testing?   Protocol may change with a static UI